# How to write generic deserializer with Spring Cloud Stream?(Batch-Consumer)

Tags: deserialization, batch-processing, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I was communicating between my cloud services. I was sending person from one service and receiving from another service and it was working without any serializer or deserializer.

My code is like that:

```
@EnableBinding({ PersonStream.class })
public class StreamConfiguration {
}
```

---

```
public interface PersonStream {

    String OUTPUT = "person-topic-out";
    String INPUT = "person-topic-in";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel inboundPerson();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel outboundPerson();
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class PersonProducer {

    @Autowired
    private PersonStream personStream;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000, initialDelay = 10000)
    public void publishPerson() {
        MessageChannel messageChannel = personStream.outboundPerson();
        Person person = new Person("Omer", "Celik");
        messageChannel.send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(person)
                        .build());
    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class PersonListener {

    @StreamListener(value = PersonStream.INPUT)
    private void personBulkReceiver(Person person) {
        System.out.println(person.getName());
    }
}
```

---

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      binders:
        defaultKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        person-topic-in:
          binder: defaultKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/person
          group : omercelik
        person-topic-out:
          binder: defaultKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/json
```

After than I needed to consume data as batch. But when I consume as batch, data types will be List. I solved that problem by writing deserializer and data types will be List. However, that way I have to write deserializer for every data. Is there a generic deserializer? How can I write generic deserializer?
I do not use avro schema. Waiting for your suggestions...

```
@Service
public class PersonListener {

    @StreamListener(value = PersonStream.INPUT)
    private void personBulkReceiver(List<Person> person) {
        System.out.println(person.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("personBulkReceiver : " + person.size());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PersonDeserializer implements Deserializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Person p = objectMapper.readValue(bytes, Person.class);
            return p;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
      binders:
        defaultKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
        bulkKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.records: 1500
                        fetch.min.bytes: 1000000
                        fetch.max.wait.ms: 10000
                        value.deserializer: tr.cloud.stream.examples.PersonDeserializer
      bindings:
        person-topic-in:
          binder: bulkKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/person
          group : omercelik
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
        person-topic-out:
          binder: defaultKafka
          destination: person-topic
          contentType: application/json
```

Codes : https://github.com/omercelikceng/spring-cloud-stream-batch-consumer